# Slow performance when calling query function in Hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

We have done a Proof of Concept (POC) with HyperLedger Composer and Fabric v1.

We have used the query functionality in Composer in our code.

We that when there are a lot of records in the chain, query performance slows down linearly.

I understand it is still an experimental feature but the degree of performance slow down is too significant. It limits the viability of putting some use cases in production.

Has anyone come across this? Any suggestion(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you experimented with adding indexes to CouchDB?

Comment: I think we can only add index to un-encrypted fields and seems only the key is un-encrypted but all the other content are encrypted inside CouchDB. This helps to a certain extent but still not a complete solution.

Comment: That is news to me -- I don't believe the default CouchDB configuration encrypts data.